# How to use select widget for Charfield in UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to render `charField` as a `select` widget in my `UpdateView`. Which i want to manipulate using `ajax`.

Form:

```
class UpdateItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    """

    TYPE_CHOICES = (('SELECT', 'SELECT'),
                    ('GOLD', 'GOLD'),
                    ('SILVER', 'SILVER'))
    type = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
                             widget=forms.Select(attrs={'required': 'required',
                                                        'onchange': 'get_names_list(this)',
                                                        }
                                                 )
                             )
    purity_percent = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, min_value=Decimal(0.1), max_value=Decimal(99.99),
                                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'required',
                                                                      'maxlength': '5',
                                                                      'size': '10',
                                                                      'class': 'per',
                                                                      'onkeypress': 'return is_number_key_purity(event)',
                                                                      'onkeyup': 'return is_number_key_purity(event)',
                                                                      'onblur': 'calculate_value()'
                                                                      }
                                                               ),
                                        )

    class Meta:

        model = Item
        exclude = ('created_by', 'updated_by',
                   'created_on'
                   )
        widgets = {'weight': forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'required',
                                                    'maxlength': '6',
                                                    'size': '12',
                                                    'onkeypress': 'return is_number_key(event)',
                                                    'onkeyup': 'return is_number_key(event)',
                                                    'onblur': 'calculate_value()'
                                                    }),
                   'remark': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'OK',
                                                   }
                                            ),
                   'deduction': forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': 'true',
                                                       'maxlength': '6',
                                                       'size': '10',
                                                       'class': 'per',
                                                       'onkeypress': 'return is_number_key(event)',
                                                       'onkeyup': 'return is_number_Key(event)',
                                                       'onblur': 'calculate_value()'
                                                       }),
                   'fine_weight': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'required': 'true',
                                                           'maxlength': '6',
                                                           'size': '10',
                                                           'value': ''
                                                           }
                                                    ),
                   'packet': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}),
                   'id': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'required': 'true'}),
                   'name': forms.Select(attrs={'required': 'required',
                                               }
                                        )
                   }
```

When my form is rendering the name field is showing up empty.

`<select id="id_item_set-0-name" maxlength="50" name="item_set-0-name" required="required">
</select>`

If i use `forms.TextInput widget` item name is showing up but i want to use `Select widget`.

Comment: So.. what is the problem here again?

Comment: Problem is when i use `select widget for CharField with UpdateView`. The rendered html is empty. Without any data. But if i use TextInput the rendered html contains the model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select widget may need your choices passed to it, as per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select).

If you need to fetch the choices with each page request, you could adjust the widget in the form constructor like so:

```
class UpdateItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.choices = Name.objects.all()
```

If that doesn't make sense, could you update your question with the model code, and clarify what choices you need to appear in the widget?

Comment: the `.widget` in the init made the difference